# Percentages and New Values

Tags: percentages

I have two values that I have calculated the percent difference with. I used the absolute difference ober the average etc. How do I go about using that percentage as a reference to calculate a difference from a different value. Example below:

I have 69" and 64". I calculate the % difference to be 7.5%
I have another value of 14" and would like to use the 7.5% difference to figure out the difference value from 14".

Would I use percent increase/decrease formula (whichever the 14" is related to) to calculate my new value?

Only way I've gotten the answer I really need is a long back calculation basically using ratios between the values I have and making my new value an unknown and my percentage a known. Is this the only way?

If I'm being too confusing I can elaborate or possibly even send a picture.

Comment: "*...to figure out the difference value from 14*" This is not clear to me. Can you rephrase that? The picture is probably helpful.

Comment: 7.5% more than 64" is 68.8" and 7.5% less than 69" is 63.825. Neither of them match. Where did you get the 7.5% difference from??

Comment: Sorry I rounded on my percentage calculation. It was mostly just for reference. Let me add a picture.